# Bad performance for hogwild-style SGD in tensorflow's word2vec

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow, word2vec

Tensorflow's gradient decent optimizer GradientDescentOptimizer does not use locking by default. If the optimizer is invoked in multiple threads in parallel - as for example [google's word2vec example](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py) - we get a hogwild-style lock-free asynchronous optimization schema.

In theory the number of updates per time (e.g. words per second in word2vec) should scale pretty much linearly. However, in the word2vec example, there is no performance gain for more than, say, three or four CPUs. I got almost no improvement by going to 16 or 32 cores. Also with large batch_sizes such as 512. CPU usage goes to up but is in parts spent on kernel operations according to htop.

Now I am wondering where the overhead comes from? If things do not lock, why don't we get at least a small performance gain?

PS: Let's keep performance in terms of accuracy aside. Large batch sizes for word2vec.py are a bad idea, I just take it as an example...

Comment: There's some discussion of bad scaling to multiple CPUs of a different task, one theory is that it is caused by thread pool locking: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/583

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that thread. Looks like the pull request is still pending... too bad...

Comment: did you ever figure out how to boost your cpu utilization?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are increasing the number of 'concurrent steps' when you talk about 'increasing the number of cores'.  Even running one concurrent step in TensorFlow will try to use all the cores on your system.  Let me know if that's not what you meant.

It's not guaranteed that you will get better performance by increasing the number of concurrent steps.   Concurrent steps only really helps when there are gaps in the execution of a single graph that can be filled by work from other graphs.  If all cores are always busy, increasing concurrent steps won't improve the number of samples per second processed.

It may be the case that the kernels used in word2vec could be either better parallelized (more effectively using the cores available on the system), or simply more optimized in general.

Comment: Yes, I mean 'concurrent steps'. So I guess it's a conflict between intra-op parallelization (not sure to what degree the word2vec ops benefit. It's mainly matmul and logistic loss) and increasing concurrent steps as a form of forced inter-op parallelization.
Maybe I should play around with intra_op_parallelism_threads.

Comment: Yeah, keep in mind that the word2vec_optimized.py example uses a custom written kernel specifically to optimize word2vec operations -- the slower version using primitive ops doesn't fuse as much work together, so you're better of experimenting with word2vec_optimized for the time being, if you care about speed.

Comment: Well, word2vec_optimized is fine if all you need is word2vec wordembeddings. If you want to extend the model, it's very inconvenient as it circumvents the whole graph backpropagation mechanism by hardcoding the gradients. For accuracy however this trick is key as the skipgram op can do real _mini-batch-free_ updates on a _batch_ of datapoints. word2vec is probably yo shallow for a deep-learning framework.